# Cannot open Zenmap.app (LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error)

Tags: applications

When I try to open it in the terminal: open Zenmap.app

I get this error:

LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Zenmap.app.

Before it asks me for my password and then I get this error.

Comment: Similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130587/lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810-downloaded-app-does-not-start though Zenmap isn't java [I think it's python, but don't quote me], but it does rely on X11 - so if you don't have that installed, that may be the reason.

Comment: Voting to reopen, as the solution in the linked Q cannot be used for this app, it's physically not an option; there is no Open With, as the OS really thinks it's an app.

Comment: X11 is installed on my computer. I am able to run WireShark.